# How services api snippets works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, facebook-pixel

I am integrating a website to Facebook Pixel, although I know I can only put the snippet on the head of the page, I am interested in understanding how this snippet works. Similar pattern happens in other services:

```
< script >
  ! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function() {
      n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
  }(window, document, 'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
fbq('track', 'PageView'); 
< /script> 
< noscript >
  <
  img height = "1"
width = "1"
style = "display:none"
src = "https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={your-pixel-id-goes-here}&ev=PageView&noscript=1" / >
< /noscript>
```

I could not understand how it is called, what means each of the arguments, what this function is expected to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating an object called fbq and attaching it to the window. It also prepends a script tag onto the page. That script tag links to the connect.facebook.net url. I assume that does more with fbq, because fbq looks pretty sparse at this point.

The snippet itself is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). It declares a function, then immediately calls it. The function takes the arguments `f, b, e, v, n, t, s` which is cute, but doesn't help anyone understand the code. When it calls the function it passes `window` to `f`, `document` to `b`, `"script"` to `e`, and the url to `v`. The other arguments are unpopulated. `n`, `t`, and `s` are all assigned inside the snippet. Having them as function parameters lets the author avoid having to `var n = ...` which is only beneficial when trying to optimize away every possible byte. Another size optimization can be seen when the author assigns things as `!0` which is `true`, but half as many characters.

Comment: Thank you Charles, you explanation will be very helpful. Uncle Bob probably cries every time he sees the kind of "cute" variables name. In this case of use of these snippets, does it still makes sense to save every single byte using these declarations and "!0"?

Comment: Not really. This particular snippet is probably on millions of pages, so it may make a difference, but most code won't benefit from this sort of optimization. A good uglifier should be enough for production.